# To get complete html of page except few div's with particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get complete html of page in javascript except few div's with particular class applied on them.I am using this to get the complete html of my document

```
    $(window.document.documentElement).html().toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$(document).contents().not('.aClass').foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
var html = $('html').clone(true);
html.find('.remove').remove();

console.log(html)​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/X38Fj/).

Note that if you then try chaining `html.toString()` you'll end up with the string `[object Object]`, not the HTML. If you you add `.toString()` after the `remove()`, in Chrome, you seem to end up with exactly the same object being passed to the console.

References:

- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 0):

You first create a copy of the documentElement, by using .clone() and storing it in a variable.

In the copied document you remove the elements you want.

```
var doc = $(window.document.documentElement).clone();
doc.find('.remove').remove();

console.log(doc.html());​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnMyj/

Comment: I dont know whats wrong but your code works fine on my normal page but not on new opened windows it gives me empty html in doc.